# Support Swing Applet and Frame in one Build

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am working on a game that I want to be embedded in a web browser and downloadable as a standalone jar. I have a subclass of `JComponent` that takes care of the game. I also have a subclass of `JApplet` and `JFrame` that display an instance of the game. If there some way I could do the following in my main method:

```
if (isEmbedded) {
    new AppletViewer();
} else {
    new FrameViewer();
}
```

or do I need to export twice, first using the `AppletViewer` and second using the `FrameViewer`?

Comment: Consider dumping the applet entirely and for the 'off the net' option, launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use a structure like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AppletBasic extends JApplet
{
    /**
     * Create the GUI. For thread safety, this method should
     * be invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private void createGUI()
    {
        JLabel appletLabel = new JLabel( "I'm a Swing Applet" );
        appletLabel.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
        appletLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 36));
        add( appletLabel );
        setSize(400, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        try
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    createGUI();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("createGUI didn't successfully complete: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JApplet applet = new AppletBasic();
        applet.init();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Applet in Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar( applet.getJMenuBar() );
        frame.setContentPane( applet.getContentPane() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        applet.start();
    }
}
```

If the class is loaded as an applet the the applet is executed as is.

If the class is loaded into a JVM then the main() method is invoked and the applet components are added to the JFrame.